# websiteUp set to false, but does not print Failure

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn Swift/Xcode and have come across an error that I can't explain.

Here is some code that should print the error code, but still prints Success even though I have changed websiteUp to false!

```
enum WebpageError: Error {
case success
case failure(Int)
}
func getWebpage(uRL: String, siteUp: Bool) throws -> String {
if siteUp == false {
    WebpageError.failure(404)
}
return "Success"
}
let webpageURL = "http://apple.com"
let websiteUp = false
do {
let status = try getWebpage(uRL: webpageURL, siteUp: websiteUp)
print(status)
} catch {
print(error)
}
```

I can't spot what is wrong, as it all looks OK to me!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two silly things:

- How can a `case` of an Error enum be a `.success`? It's for failures!
- It isn't enough to *say* `WebpageError.failure`. You have to `throw` the error.

So:

```
enum WebpageError: Error {
    case failure(Int) // <== look
}
func getWebpage(uRL: String, siteUp: Bool) throws -> String {
    if !siteUp {
        throw WebpageError.failure(404) // <== look
    }
    return "Success"
}
let webpageURL = "http://apple.com"
let websiteUp = false
do {
    let status = try getWebpage(uRL: webpageURL, siteUp: websiteUp)
    print(status)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Having said all that, let's go back to the question of why you included a `.success` case. Maybe your idea was to return a value signalling success or failure. That would be a Result. Like this:

```
enum WebpageError: Error {
    case failure(Int)
}
func getWebpage(uRL: String, siteUp: Bool) -> Result<String,Error> {
    return Result {
        if !siteUp {
            throw WebpageError.failure(404)
        }
        return "Success"
    }
}
let webpageURL = "http://apple.com"
let websiteUp = false
let status = getWebpage(uRL: webpageURL, siteUp: websiteUp)
do {
    try print(status.get())
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

That might be more sophisticated than you had in mind at this stage, but it's worth thinking about.

Comment: I must be getting too old for programming. Sometimes the error is staring me in the face (I'm 73). Missed 'throw' in function!

Comment: If my answer was correct and helpful please _accept_ it. You are not accepting enough answers; people will stop helping you if you don't play the game.